# Batch Clipping of shapefiles in FME

Tags: shapefile, clip, fme-form, transformer, fme-transformer

I have 250 shapefiles of large area. I have a area shapefile against which I want to clip the small portion of all 250 shapefiles. I tried using transformer Clipper individually on each shapefile as reader and output on individually writer.

As it is lengthy process to assign Clipper to 250 readers individually.

Is there any process to clip all shapes using single clip transformer and output to 250 layers.

Comment: Have you checked this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95503/most-efficient-way-to-batch-clip-in-fme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you can do a dynamic reader and writer and clip them all at once, for sure.

First, with your reader, make sure you use 'single merged feature type'.

[image: Reader]

For your writer, make it 'dynamic' so that it gets the schema from input featuretypes.

[image: Writer]

And now you clip in the middle. This will work generically and write files our named the same as the input.

[image]